# error while creating the signed apk in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, build

While creating the signed **apk** in **react native** android, I'm getting below error in the final step

> Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
>   Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.
>
> Task :app:processReleaseManifest
>   C:\React\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:13:5-42:19 Warning:
>           application@android:allowBackup was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:13 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
>
> C:\React\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png:
>   error: uncompiled PNG file passed as argument. Must be compiled first
>   into .flat file.. error: failed parsing overlays.

Any helps will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First Bundle the react-native code with android in the command line

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

After successful completion of bundling then go to android studio and clean the project. If no error occurs then generate signed apk through Build->Generate Signed APK.

> Change the name for the entry file at --entry-file to the one which
>   you are using.

Comment: But i'm not working on android studio . i'm working in react native in vscode. how can i clean the project.

Comment: C:\React>react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\React\node_modules (52ms)
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\React\node_modules (85ms)
Loading dependency graph, done.
Loading dependency graph...
Cannot find entry file index.android.js in any of the roots: ["C:\\React"]

Comment: I have mentioned to change the entry file. If your index file is named index.js and not index.android.js then change only --entry-file index.android.js to --entry-file index.js in the command line

Comment: vs code is used only to develop react native project. And you need android studio or eclipse or other developement kits to generate apk. If you doesn't want to use developement kits then you have to use corresponding command line code within the android directory whick may be complex. Try installing any android developement kits and generate signed apk from the kit after bundling the code with android

Comment: I'm still getting the same  error after 
C:\React\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png: error: uncompiled PNG file passed as argument. Must be compiled first into .flat file..
error: failed parsing overlays.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.

Comment: i have android studio also but the code i'm doing is react native soo i can't make signed apk in android studio.

Comment: Please try to understand that you will develop project in react native but the apk can only be generated through sdk. I think it may be the solution for resource file. Go to gradle and add/change **android.enableAapt2=false**. Please check https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3097 for further reference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179159/discussion-between-saravanan-and-shabnam-singh).

Answer (score 0):

Set as below in the gradle.properties file:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Now sync gradle.

If still not fixed, manually delete all the build folders in the project and reassemble.

Comment: how can i sync the project in react native

Answer (score 0):

FIRST: Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'. Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.
 => can fix by @Saravanan mentioned.
SECOND: error: uncompiled PNG file passed as argument. Must be compiled first into .flat file.. error: failed parsing overlays. 
 => can fix by @sdn404 mentioned.
THIRD: If you still have any issue, try to replace `android.enableAapt2=false` with `org.gradle.configureondemand=true` then run command `cd android && ./gradlew clean` then `./gradlew assembleRelease` 
Hope this help.